# Adding Yogaglo as supported youtube-dl site

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I would like to add Yogaglo support for youtube-dl.

I've followed guidance on [Github](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl) .

And have drafted the following:

```
# coding: utf-8
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from .common import InfoExtractor


class YogagloIE(InfoExtractor):
 _SIGNIN_URL = 'https://www.yogaglo.com/login'
 _PASSWORD_URL = 'https://www.yogaglo.com/login/password'
 _USER_URL = 'https://www.yogaglo.com/login/user'
 _ACCOUNT_CREDENTIALS_HINT = 'Use --username and --password options to provide yogaglo.com account credentials.'
_NETRC_MACHINE = 'yogaglo'


def _real_initialize(self):
    self._login()

_VALID_URL = r'https?://(?:www\.)?yogaglo\.com/class/(?P<id>[0-9]+)'
_TEST = {
    'url': 'https://www.yogaglo.com/class/7206',
    'md5': 'TODO: md5 sum of the first 10241 bytes of the video file (use --test)',
    'info_dict': {
        'id': '7206',
        'ext': 'mp4',
        'title': 'Have a Great Day!'
        # TODO more properties, either as:
        # * A value
        # * MD5 checksum; start the string with md5:
        # * A regular expression; start the string with re:
        # * Any Python type (for example int or float)
    }
}

def _real_extract(self, url):
    video_id = self._match_id(url)
    webpage = self._download_webpage(url, video_id)
    title = self._html_search_regex(r'<h1>(.+?)</h1>', webpage, 'title')

    return {
        'id': video_id,
        'title': title,
        'description': self._og_search_description(webpage),
        'uploader': self._search_regex(r'<div[^>]+id="uploader"[^>]*>([^<]+)<', webpage, 'uploader', fatal=False),
        # TODO more properties (see youtube_dl/extractor/common.py)
    }
```

I've added yogagloIE to the list of extractors and when I run it I get an error that the URL is not supported. This is really a first draft and any guidance on hoe to improve it and make it work is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, indentation is significant, so make sure you indent your class correctly.

After that, you must define a `_login` method or simply leave `_real_initialize` empty.

With that being implemented, the extractor will be called (although of course it's not functional yet):

```
$ youtube-dl test:yogaglo
[TestURL] Test URL: https://www.yogaglo.com/class/7206
[Yogaglo] 7206: Downloading webpage
ERROR: Unable to extract title; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.
```

You can pull this working state with the following command (maybe `git stash` everything beforehand, and rename your old yogaglo.py file to something else):

```
git pull https://github.com/phihag/youtube-dl.git yogaglo
```